# Regex don't match at all if there is a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to match this pattern:

```
] 1 some words 2 some other words 3 some other words
```

but not match if it's:

```
] 1 some words 2 some other words 3 T
```

or

```
] 1 some words 2 some other words 3 some other words 4 words 5 words
```

For instance, I would like to match this:

```
e   fare   …   incontro]   1 p       2 perchè   dopo   quell       3 e
```

This is my attempt, but it doesn't work properly:

```
\]\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)\s*3\s*([\w\s][^\W\d_T]+)
```

Rules:
- do not match at all if there is "3 T"
- do not match at all if after "3" there is 4 or 5

Comment: What are the *rules*? *Why* do you want to match "this" and why not "that"?

Comment: can you define the rule why some strings you want and some you don't, otherwise we cant provide much help.

Comment: *Match this pattern* Does that mean from start of the string to the end of the string? You need to clarify this question...

Comment: I edited my question, let me know if it's clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your regex, I think I understand what you are trying. I guess you were close:

```
(?!.*\s4\s)\]\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)\s*3\s*([^\d_T]+)\b(?:\s)
```

In your pattern, change:

```
([\w\s][^\W\d_T]+)
```

to

```
([^\d_T]+)\b(?:\s)          - match any character except digit or _ or T until a word boundary followed by a non-capturing space
```

And add to beginning

```
(?!.*\s4\s)                     - do not match if line contains space+4+space
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oQ0C1/2)

Comment: Thank you, but about  excluding 4 and 5... if they are after the 3 I do not want to match at all

Comment: @Anna updated answer